# Identify and subset rows with some similar information

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset containing reports on financial transactions. Each row corresponds to one report. However, when a mistake is made on a report, a second “Error report” is generated to cancel the report containing the mistake.

```
Case Study
  ID            DATE          NB        ERRORS
1 06054B149     20160526      95131     -   
2 06054B149     20160526      95132     -         
3 06054B149     20160526      95133     -         
4 06054B149     20160526      95134     -  
5 06054B149     20160526      95135     -         
6 06054B149     20160526      95136     -   
7 06054B149     20160526      95134     X
```

My goal is to find both the reports containing the mistakes (here row 4) and the corresponding “Error reports” that cancel them (row 7), and take them out of the dataset.

“Error reports” are marked with an X, and are therefore easy to identify. What is more complex is to identify the corresponding reports containing the mistakes (“Mistakes”).

“Mistakes” share some similar data with “Error reports”. In this example, I have given ID, DATE and NB, but there are 11 characteristics that can be used to identify mistakes precisely (out of 40 in total).

What I have done is the following:

```
ErrorReports <- CaseStudy[(CaseStudy$ERRORS == "X"),]

Mistakes <- subset(CaseStudy, (NB %in% ErrorReports$NB)
                 &(DATE %in% ErrorReports$DATE)
                 &(ID %in% ErrorReports$ID))

Filtered <- anti_join(CaseStudy,Mistakes)
```

However, this is not precise enough, and when I apply this code to (very) large datasets, it identifies too many “Mistakes”, instead of precisely the same amount as “Error Reports”.

How do I identify “Mistakes” precisely?

Hope this is understandable.

Comment: You should show an example of the desired ouput. I think the package dplyr could be useful here.

Comment: You are using `anti_join` with all columns. Maybe you need `anti_join(CaseStudy, Mistakes, by = c("ID", "DATE", "NB"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `ave` to flag any record with an `X` by corresponding *ID*, *DATE*, and *NB* (`ifelse` to render column to numeric):

```
CaseStudy$CHECK <- with(CaseStudy, ave(ifelse(ERRORS=='X', 1, 0), ID, DATE, NB, FUN=max))

Mistakes <- CaseStudy[CaseStudy$CHECK == 1,]
Mistakes
#          ID     DATE    NB ERRORS CHECK
# 4 06054B149 20160526 95134      -     1
# 7 06054B149 20160526 95134      X     1

Filtered <- CaseStudy[CaseStudy$CHECK == 0,]    
Filtered
#          ID     DATE    NB ERRORS CHECK
# 1 06054B149 20160526 95131      -     0
# 2 06054B149 20160526 95132      -     0
# 3 06054B149 20160526 95133      -     0
# 5 06054B149 20160526 95135      -     0
# 6 06054B149 20160526 95136      -     0
```

Comment: Nice! A bit shorter version with `+(ERRORS == "x")` should work I think.

Comment: I've modified my code to take your solution under account, but it's been running for 30 minutes now. I guess this is normal since it's considerably more precise, but it seems I don't have sufficient processing power to deal with this issue.

Comment: Your data must be very large as I missed that small note. Curious did data derive from a database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "database". I'm taking my data from a database called TRACE, but the data I used originates from a csv file. I don't know if that answers your question !

Answer (score 0):

Based on *"However, when a mistake is made on a report, a second “Error report” is generated to cancel the report containing the mistake"*, **it seems that only the reports with errors would have duplicates** in your data. Here's a simpler way of removing them -

```
identifiers <- c("ID", "DATE", "NB") # you have 11 of these in actual data

# identify duplicates using only the identifiers and ignoring the ERRORS column
bad_report_ind <- duplicated(CaseStudy[, identifiers]) | 
                    duplicated(CaseStudy[, identifiers], fromLast = TRUE)

clean_reports <- CaseStudy[!bad_report_ind, ]
```

As for your way with `anti_join`, you probably need to join using only the `identifiers`.

```
Filtered <- dplyr::anti_join(CaseStudy, Mistakes, by = identifiers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer of Shree but a bit shorter. It will do if you are only interested in the clean data frame:

```
Filtered <- CaseStudy %>% group_by(NB) %>% filter(n() == 1)
```

This should filter out all mistakes and all error reports. From you sample data I get the impression that only the column NB is relevant, but if not, you can group by more identifiers.